# Sending a few characters over local wifi network via Xcode

Tags: cocoa, swift3, xcode8

I've found a few tutorials on ways to do this in iOS applications, but I'm trying to build a program for my iMac to control some smart bulbs. I need to send a few characters over the local network to the Wifi Bridge which controls the lights. No response is needed.

I had this going in a Java program, but wanted to switch to Xcode for the interface. I'm using Xcode 8, Swift 3, in a Cocoa application.

Any idea where to start? I think once I figure out the command and syntax I should be good to go.